# json retreive data multiple nested

Tags: php, json

I am able to put some of attributes of json file contents from some api but category is not showing its value. The image file is for the json contents structure.

[image: Image description]

Below it the code attached

```
<?php
    if (count($data->products)){?>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dataTable" id="dataTable" aria-describedby="dataTable_info">
            <thead>
                <tr role="row">
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Rendering engine: activate to sort column ascending">ID</th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Browser: activate to sort column ascending">Title</th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Category</th>
                    <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Price</th>
                    <!-- <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Platform(s): activate to sort column ascending">Thumbnail</th> -->
                    <!-- <th class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Engine version: activate to sort column ascending">Password</th> -->
                    <!--<th class="sorting_asc" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="dataTable" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="CSS grade: activate to sort column descending">Ref_code</th> -->

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!--<tfoot>
                <tr><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Rendering engine</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Browser</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Platform(s)</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">Engine version</th><th rowspan="1" colspan="1">CSS grade</th></tr>
            </tfoot>-->

        <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
            <?php // Cycle through the array
                foreach ($data->products as $idx => $products){?>
                    <tr class="gradeA odd">         
                        <td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->id; ?></td>
                        <td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->title; ?></td>
                        <td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->category->name; ?></td>
                        <td class=" "><?php if ($products->info->title=='Levels of Spiritual Attainment') { echo $products->pricing->combined; } else { echo $products->pricing->amount; }  ?></td>
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->thumbnail; ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php if ($user->field_name == "your-email") { echo $user->field_value; }  ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php if ($user->field_name == "your-subject") { echo $user->field_value; }  ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php if ($user->field_name == "menu-932") { echo $user->field_value; }  ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php if ($user->field_name == "your-message") { echo $user->field_value; }  ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php echo $user->pass; ?></td> -->
                        <!-- <td class=" "><?php echo $user->ref_code; ?></td> -->

                    </tr>

                <?php } ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php } 
?>
```

Comment: Could you specify your question?

Comment: hi @ritchie46 . attached it the code and image. the image has the structure of the json data , i am able to fetch the other attributes but for category it is not working please see the image and code you will surely understand

Comment: I think, you should also add the PHP tag to question, than somebody who programs in PHP can help you. ;)

Comment: Images of code  / data / exceptions are not OK (alone). Please edit your question and include JSON document as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to get the information from an array as it was an object.

Try to change this line :

```
<td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->category->name; ?></td>
```

by :

```
<td class=" "><?php echo $products->info->category[0]->name; ?></td>
```

Of course, if always better to check the quantity of categories before.

Comment: Hey @Syscall that was perfectly works! Thanks